# How to write an Object with list into csv file using univocity writer

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Java bean `A` as follows

```
String name;
List<Address> address;
```

and `Address` is again a bean as follows

```
String city;
int pinCode;
```

When using `@Parsed` annotation of univocity bean writer processor the address field is written as object in csv file. How to make that to print the city and pincode values?

This is my code to generate CSV file

```
File csvFile = File.createTempFile("NEW" + ".csv", "");
Writer out = new FileWriter(csvFile);

FixedWidthFieldLengths lengths = new FixedWidthFieldLengths(30, 20);
FixedWidthWriterSettings settings = new FixedWidthWriterSettings(lengths);

// Creates a BeanWriterProcessor that handles annotated fields in the UserVo class.
settings.setRowWriterProcessor(new BeanWriterProcessor<UserVO>(UserVO.class));

// Sets the file headers
settings.setHeaders("Username", "listOfAddresses");

// Creates a writer with the above settings;
FixedWidthWriter writer = new FixedWidthWriter(out, settings);

// Writes the headers specified in the settings
writer.writeHeaders();

// writes a fixed width row with empty values (new UserVO instance).
writer.processRecord(new UserVO());

// writes values of UserVO
writer.processRecords(userVOs);

writer.close();

response().setContentType("text/csv");
response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + csvFile.getName());
return ok(csvFile);
```

and the `UserVO` mapped to output file with `@Parsed` annotation as follows

```
public class UserVO {
    @NullString(nulls = { "?", "-" })
    @LowerCase
    @Parsed
    private String username;

    @Parsed
    private List<Address> listOfAddresses;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Address> getListOfAddresses() {
        return listOfAddresses;
    }

    public void setListOfAddresses(List<Address> listOfAddresses) {
        this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code where your writing in CSV

Comment: @Sarz Have posted the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can create a custom conversion class to handle any arbitrary elements you have in your bean. Check the following section of the [tutorial](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial): **Using your own conversions in annotations**

Using your own example, I created the following custom conversion to print objects in a collection:

```
public class CollectionConversion implements Conversion<String, Collection<?>> {

private String separator = "|";

public CollectionConversion(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        separator = args[0];
    }
}

@Override
public Collection<?> execute(String input) {
    return null;
}

//You only need to implement this one when writing.
@Override
public String revert(Collection<?> input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object element : input) {
        if (out.length() > 0) {
            out.append(this.separator);
        }
        out.append(element.toString());
    }
    return out.toString();
}
}
```

This implementation relies on the **toString()** of the elements in your collection, so my Address class looks like this:

```
public class Address {
    String city;
    int pinCode;

    public String toString() {
        return city + " (" + pinCode + ")";
    }
}
```

Now, in your UserVO class you can specify the list of addresses like this:

```
@Convert(conversionClass = CollectionConversion.class, args = { ";" })
@Parsed
private List<Address> listOfAddresses;
```

In my test I created a few addresses:
        ...
        writer.processRecord(new UserVO());

```
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    Address a = new Address();
    a.city = "New York";
    a.pinCode = 14;

    Address b = new Address();
    b.city = "Sydney";
    b.pinCode = 345;

    addresses.add(a);
    addresses.add(b);

    UserVO vo1 = new UserVO();
    vo1.setUsername("User1");
    vo1.setListOfAddresses(addresses);

    List<UserVO> userVOs = new ArrayList<UserVO>();
    userVOs.add(vo1);

    writer.processRecords(userVOs);
    ...
```

I changed the length of the second field from 20 to 50 (othwerwise the output will be tructed). This will produce:

```
Username                      listOfAddresses                                   
?                                                                               
user1                         New York (14);Sydney (345)
```

Comment: Yeah this will be the solution to print the values of a collection. But if the city and pincode values are need to be printed as columns, then we have to declare them as individual fields in UserVO class

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same univocity writer for writing the object to csv file. some data is writing as null. Before writing it. I'm logging it and i'm able to see the data. But onces its completed writing it is reflecting as null in csv file.

```
settings.setRowWriterProcessor(new BeanWriterProcessor<Employee>(Employee.class));

writers.writeHeaders("added headers here");

List<Employee> employeeList = service.generatereport(start,enddate);

for(employeel:employeeList) {

//here when i print the values of employeel.getSomethings - i'm getting the value

writer.processRecord(employeel);

//in csv it is null.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, format in the sense, do i need to use any method called format from univocity?

Comment: Can you please respond i' ve stuck here from past 3 hours.